# Splitting an array by 16 characters then putting each of the parts into an array

Tags: java, arrays

It's a very simple problem but at the moment my brain is fried from working on other parts of this project so I need help.  I have a string of a size of a multiple of 16(example: size 16, 32, 48 etc.) I need to break that string into smaller strings of length 16 and place them into an array of size string.length()/16

For example we'll say my string(appendSourceBinary) is: "1000101101001001"

Here's my non working code:

```
String[] holding = new String[appendSourceBinary.length()/16];
                int counter;
                for(int z = 0; z < appendSourceBinary.length(); z++){
                    holding[z] = appendSourceBinary.substring(z, z+16);
                }
```

Comment: Put just a few more lines of code within that for loop. Try using the remainder operator, `%` to help you out. Most important -- don't give up and come here so soon -- work it out on paper, and keep at it.

Comment: Increment for your loop will not be 1.

Comment: It could be, do `appendSourceBinary.substring(16z, 16z+16)`, then also do `z < holding.length()`

Comment: Son of a gun it is z+=16.  Sorry guys it's been a long day

Answer (score 1):

There is a regex to do this just using split:

```
String[] array = appendSourceBinary.split("(?<=\\G.{16})");
```

The regex splits on points in the string proceeded (asserted using a look behind) by the end of the last match (`\G`) followed by 16 characters (`.{16}`). Conveniently, `\G` is initially set to start of input.

---

Some test code:

```
String appendSourceBinary = "A234567890123456B234567890123456C234567890123456";
String[] array = appendSourceBinary.split("(?<=\\G.{16})");
Arrays.stream(array).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
A234567890123456
B234567890123456
C234567890123456
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in two lines, without a loop, like this:

```
    String appendSourceBinary = "10101010101010101010101010101010";
    String[] split = appendSourceBinary.replaceAll("([01]{16})", "$1x").split("x");
```

I've used a regular expression search and replace to find each group of sixteen characters in the string and to replace them with themselves followed by an x. Then I've split the string on the x, leaving an array containing the groups of 16 characters.

If you add a simple loop to output the results:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
        System.out.println(split[i]);
```

you'll find the output is

```
1010101010101010
1010101010101010
```

Which is the original 32 char string I used split in two 16 char strings. Any remainder will be returned as the last element of the array. If there are less than 16 chars in the input string they'll be returned as the first and only array entry.